# Android password manager that imports LastPass passwords

Tags: gratis, android, password-manager

I'm searching for a free Android password manager that

- integrates with Firefox Android version easily
- imports my passwords that I have exported from LastPass to a CSV file
- (Bonus) allows syncing with Dropbox or Google Drive

I use LastPass on my computers, I want a free alternative on Android since I very rarely use my phone to browse the web and login, so I won't pay for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [keeper password](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callpod.android_apps.keeper&hl=en) manager, imported the csv using their [web portal](https://keepersecurity.com/vault/).

The downside is that no firefox integration, they claim that it works on any browser, I'm going to report the bug on firefox and see how it goes. It works on Chrome and other browsers. And backups are limited for none premium users.

**Update**

Keeper support gave me 6 months premium membership for reporting Firefox bug, they are working to fix it, I will update my answer when the issue is fixed. I'm thinking to stay with them simply because the support is nice, it's good to know that when you report an issue, someone is listening.

Comment: I'm going to accept my answer but if someone has a better solution, I will reaccept his answer instead of mine.